# MySQL - Select where timestamp is midnight

Tags: mysql, select, timestamp

I have a table with a timestamp column in it and I want to select any rows of any date where the time is 00:00:00

Is there a better way to do this other than filtering on the last 8 characters as a substring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the TIME() function.

```
WHERE TIME(yourfield) = '00:00:00'
```